# Excel VBA Web Scraping - Ignore One of Multiple Tables via XML HTTP Request

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I could really use some help figuring out a piece of a web scraping code I can't seem to get to work:

- **Short version of my question:  Is there a way to write into a XML HTTP Request code to ignore a table on a webpage?**

Long version of my question:  The page has 10 tables of football players (some with a couple rows, some with several...each "small" table represents a tier).  The last table on the page - with table id = "table_10" - is a large, comprehensive table of all positions...not just quarterbacks (which the page and smaller tables are dedicated to)

- Image examples: [Smaller Tier Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cghgz.png) / / / [All Players Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AfFR.png).

With the below code, I only get "table_10" in my Excel sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ETR_QB_Tiers_XMLHTTP()

   Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
   Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

   XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://establishtherun.com/2020-tiers-of-evan-quarterbacks/", False
   XMLPage.send

   If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then
      MsgBox XMLPage.Status & " - " & XMLPage.statusText
      Exit Sub
   End If

   HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

   ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc

End Sub
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

   Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
   Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer

   Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

   For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
      'Debug.Print HTMLTable.ID

      Sheets("XMLHTTP").Select

      RowNum = 1
      For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
         'Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLRow.innerText

         ColNum = 1
         For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
            'Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLCell.innerText
            Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
         Next HTMLCell

         RowNum = RowNum + 1

      Next HTML Row

   Next HTMLTable

End Sub
```

When I set the code to `Debug.Print HTMLTable.ID` with the `For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables` line of the **ProcessHTMLPage** sub, I am presented all 10 table IDs in the Immediate Window:

```
table_1
table_2
table_3
. . .
table_10
```

When I set the code to `Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLRow.innertext` with the `For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables` line, I am presented results for both smaller tables (tables 1 through 9) and the large table (table 10) in the Immediate Window:

```
table_1
   TierOne
   Patrick Mahomes (QB1)Lamar Jackson (QB2)
table_2
   TierTwo
   Dak Prescott (QB3)Josh Allen (QB4)
   Deshaun Watson (QB5)Russell Wilson (QB6)
   Kyler Murray (QB7)
. . .
table_10
   RankWRRBTEQB
   1Michael Thomas (1)Christian McCaffrey (1)Travis Kelce (1)Patrick Mahomes (1)
   2Davante Adams (1)Ezekiel Elliott (1)George Kittle (1)Lamar Jackson (1)
   3Tyreek Hill (1)Saquon Barkley (1)Zach Ertz (1)Dak Prescott (2)
   ...
```

So - I know those "smaller" table are there and accessible, but the code spits out only the comprehensive "table_10" (below) while I'm really wanting the separate tables 1 through 9 - not table 10 at all:

Again...is there a way to ignore "table_10" and ensure I'm given tables 1 through 9 (instead of just "table_10")?  I've tried to incorporate 'If' statements so many ways now that I've lost count.

---

***Bonus question*** - the "smaller" tables are set up in a Z-pattern (i.e. - cell A1 is Player #1 > cell B1 is Player #2 > cell A2 is Player #3 > cell B2 is Player #4, etc.).  Is there a way to get players in Column B to come over to Column A in their ranked order?  Basically, convert two columns to one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overwriting the tables so you only see the last table (being the largest it likely overwrites everything from before).

Try moving `RowNum = 1` to before the loop over tables otherwise I think you reset for each table and overwrite.

You might also want to add an r + 1 before `Next HTMLTable` so as to have some whitespace between tables.

Here is a trivial example to demonstrate:

**Your logic:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Demo_XMLHTTP()

   Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
   Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

   XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp", False
   XMLPage.send

   If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then
      MsgBox XMLPage.Status & " - " & XMLPage.statusText
      Exit Sub
   End If

   HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

   ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc

End Sub


Public Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

   Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   Dim HTMLTables()
   Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Long
   Dim hTable As Variant

   HTMLTables = Array(1, 2, 3)

   For Each hTable In HTMLTables

      Set HTMLTable = HTMLPage.getElementById("customers") '<== yeah same table but imagine it is different

      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XMLHTTP").Select

      RowNum = 1

      With ActiveSheet

      For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")

         ColNum = 1

         For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
            .Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
         Next HTMLCell

         RowNum = RowNum + 1

      Next HTMLRow
      Set HTMLTable = Nothing
      .Cells(RowNum, ColNum + 1) = hTable '< note which iteration we are viewing
      End With

   Next hTable

End Sub
```

**Versus:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Demo_XMLHTTP()

   Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
   Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

   XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp", False
   XMLPage.send

   If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then
      MsgBox XMLPage.Status & " - " & XMLPage.statusText
      Exit Sub
   End If

   HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

   ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc

End Sub


Public Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

   Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   Dim HTMLTables()
   Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Long
   Dim hTable As Variant

   HTMLTables = Array(1, 2, 3)

   RowNum = 1

   For Each hTable In HTMLTables

      Set HTMLTable = HTMLPage.getElementById("customers") '<== yeah same table but imagine it is different

      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XMLHTTP").Select

      With ActiveSheet

      For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")

         ColNum = 1

         For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
            .Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
         Next HTMLCell

         RowNum = RowNum + 1

      Next HTMLRow
      Set HTMLTable = Nothing
      .Cells(RowNum, ColNum + 1) = hTable '< note which iteration we are viewing
      End With

   Next hTable

End Sub
```

---

**Ignore table 10:**

You can use a `For i = 0 To  HTMLTables.Length - 2`, rather than `For Each`, to ignore last table. Access any given table with  `HTMLTables.item(i)`. Otherwise, you could test the id and ignore based on that, or even based on index (remember to -1). I would probably use id as more reliable. Normally, you would run to `.Length-1`.

---

**Bonus:**

I can't run against your test page but if you do a `For Loop`, you can adjust the column to write out to, depending on whether `i` is odd or even (use `MOD` for example); `Odd number MOD 2 = 1`; `Even MOD 2 = 0` then adjust `ColNum` with -1, or as appropriate.

Comment: Hi @QHarr - your idea to move `RowNum = 1` before the loop worked like a charm!  I'm very much a VBA newb, so I'm struggling to understand and apply your other suggestions. (separate comments below)

Comment: **Ignore table 10:** Are you suggesting to replace the entire line of `For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables` with `For i = 0 To HTMLTables.Length - 2`? By doing that and adding a `Next i` line in place of `Next HTMLTable`, I get an error saying "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" at the `For Each HTMLRow...` line (I also declared `Dim i As Integer`)

Comment: For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTables.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("tr") https://pastebin.com/AufzGKhC

Comment: Any other questions please ask away

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you for that solution! I adjusted the last `Next HTMLTable` to `Next i` (it was giving me an error on that line) and it works!!

Comment: **Bonus:** I think I may have an alternate way to get all the results in one column, but some tables have nothing in the last cell.  Is there a way to ignore or skip over those?

Comment: Yes.... test if the td.innerText <> vbNullString In your case HTMLCell.innerText <> vbNullString

Comment: You are a saint, @QHarr!  Thank you for your help and patience with me on this!

Comment: Not a problem. You are most welcome. Nice to see how much effort you put into asking a nice and clear question and trying out things for yourself.